# How to restrict call to Azure Function , N number of time from given machine/ip

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Suppose user feedback/suggestion from site is implemented using azure function; how to avoid  same user or same machine making azure function call infinite number of time ? how to restrict call from same machine say 2-3 times in day

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement it on Azure Functions, you'll need to store on Azure Redis Cache the ips / number of calls. If it reaches the max amount, return 429 HTTTP Response.

As another option, you can put API Management in front of your Azure functions and implement a rate limit policy:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-sample-flexible-throttling#ip-address-throttling